# <video> not loading on mobile, works perfectly on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The website I'm making seems to work fine on desktop, but sometimes on phone individual `<video>` tags don't load - they just show up blank. If I hold down my finger where the video should be, it allows me to download it (so it is there, kind of, but it doesn't show up.) It doesn't seem to be consistent, different ones fail on different attempts.

My website is here: http://www.theochitayat.com
You can see the problem if you click one of the projects on the list.

My main guess is that it has to do with the fact that all my html is being run on `index.html`, and when a new project is clicked, I load in a new html page into its div using `jquery.load()`. What's weird is that I would expect this to either work for all entries, or work for none.

Two other guesses are that my videos have autoplay on (but they are also muted), and because the videos are quicktime (and I have added `type="video/mp4"` as suggested from another post.

I'm really lost, all of these problems should either break every video, or break none. Does anyone know why this might happen?

Comment: For  debugging Android Chrome from Windows, Linux, or Mac, you may refer to the following web page:


https://raygun.com/blog/debug-android-chrome/

Comment: I'll try this to see if any errors pop up thank you - but it occurs on android and ios

Comment: You wouldn't want to use Youtube for this? It would probably give you a little SEO boost.